# Nested canvas saving as a single image

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl

I have a canvas element called glCanvas. I wanted to append some text to it. glCanvas had a webGL rendering context so getContext('2d') did not work. Hence I created a new 2d canvas and made that the child of glCanvas:

```
    var Glcanvas = document.getElementById("glCanvas");


    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute("id","canvas");
    canvas.width="512";
    canvas.height="512";
    Glcanvas.appendChild(canvas);

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var text = "element";//overlay.elementIDs[i];

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);

    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,255)';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2.5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = 'bold 80px Verdana';

    var leftOffset = ctx.canvas.width/2;
    var rightOffset = ctx.canvas.height/2;
    ctx.strokeText(text,leftOffset,rightOffset);
    ctx.fillText(text,leftOffset,rightOffset);
    ctx.save();
```

Later I try to save my glCanvas onto an image.

```
    var imageUrl = glCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);

    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', imageUrl);
    pom.setAttribute('download', 'image_C' + cameraIndex + '.jpg');

    document.body.appendChild(pom);

    pom.click();

    document.body.removeChild(pom);
```

Over here, my text that I created isnt getting saved. How do I make sure both of them get saved?

Comment: DOM elements and canvas bitmaps are two very separate things. You have to draw each bitmap (from each canvas) onto a new one (or reuse one of them).

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want to draw the WebGL canvas into the 2d canvas.

```
ctx = ctx.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(glCanvas, imageX, imageY);
ctx.fillText("sometext", textX, textY);
```

Now you can get a screenshot of the 2D canvas

```
var dataURL = ctx.canvas.toDataURL();
```

Also note, IIRC children of a canvas do not get displayed unless the browser doesn't support canvas (Which only is only really old browsers at this point)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have a small issue here. It wasnt mentioned in my question and hence I am putting it here : I have stuff that is being drawn into glCanvas already. I want give them text labels and hence created the 2d canvas. I have about 150 elements and I was actually creating 150 small canvases to put the text labels into and add them to glcanvas. I am not sure how it will work if I reverse it the way you are saying

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Your question says "**saving as a single image**" which sounds like you wanted a screenshot with labels. If you want a screenshot that's easy. Draw the glCanvas into the 2d-canvas then draw 150 labels on the 2d-canvas, then call toDataURL on the 2d-canvas. If instead you actually wanted to display 150 labels and the screenshot is irrelevant then please re-write your question.